# Boneless Frozen Lamb Roast

Tags: jam, lamb

I was wondering if anybody has ever done a Boneless Lamb Roast in a slow-cooker and what the results were ,Thank you,Larry

Comment: Hi and welcome - it's a little hard to tell what information you're looking for.  Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: Hello Larry, and welcome to Seasoned advice. It seems that you just want to hear examples of how it went. This is not the kind of question we can answer here, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. If you had an actual question and not an invitation to share experiences, please edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to cook a lamb roast with or without bones in a slow-cooker. Slow-cooking meat tends to give a nice and tender result. [However, it is strongly recommended to thaw it first](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/can-i-put-frozen-meat-in-a-slow-cooker). It takes a long time for a slow cooker to get the food up to a cooking temperature from frozen which is [a food safety issue](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/appliances-and-thermometers/slow-cookers-and-food-safety/ct_index).